# strpos() works only sometimes

Tags: php, explode, strpos

I have been trying to use `PHP` function `strpos()` in my code.
I don't know why this code doesn't work.
If I try to use a custom string that contains my 'b' tag, it works. If I try to get the string by my array, it doesn't work. I've tried also in this way : `strpos('<b>',$textArray[$i])`, but it's useless.

PS: The (string) cast doesn't work.

```
<?php
$path="description/1.txt";
    $myfile = fopen($path, "r");
    $buffer="";
    if ($myfile) {
        $buffer=htmlspecialchars(fread($myfile,filesize($path)), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        fclose($myfile);
    }
    $textArray= explode(" ", $buffer);
    for($i=0;$i<count($textArray);$i++){

        $tmp="test string <b> :) ";

        if(strpos($textArray[$i],'<b>',0)===false){
            echo "Didn't find  ";
        }else{
            echo "YEES :D  ";
        }
    }

 ?>
```

Array var_dump():

```
array(10) {
 [0]=>
 string(15) "sadsad<b>"
 [1]=>
 string(16) "asdw</b>ad"
 [2]=>
 string(24) "a<b>sdsa</b>"
 [3]=>
 string(9) "<b>"
 [4]=>
 string(4) "dsad"
 [5]=>
 string(3) "sad"
 [6]=>
 string(3) "sad"
 [7]=>
 string(9) "asdsadsad"
 [8]=>
 string(6) "sadsad"
 [9]=>
 string(8) "sadsadas"
}
```

Comment: remove call to `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 1):

As you use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) which will convert things like `<` to `&lt;`, you will never find `<b>`.

So remove the call to `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
$buffer=fread($myfile,filesize($path));
```

Comment: Why in var_dump i can see  '<b>'?

Comment: If you display `&lt;b&gt;` in a browser - it will convert this back to `<b>`

Comment: @EliaFrati - Right click on the page and choose "View source" and you'll see what the string actually looks like.

Comment: Sure, i get it. But if i try to echo $textArray[$i]; i can see the '<b>'. The string contains the '<b>'. I've just tried to print all the array and the echo print something like that "sadsad<b>" not like this "sadsad&lt;b&gt;".
Anyway, thank's a lot. I've changed the if control instead the htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 0):

Try removing htmlspecialchars
It should work.